# 500 Error on localhost after standard setup for Strapi and Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, strapi, nuxtjs3

I tried to setup a Strapi installation with a new Nuxt App. But when I try to access it with the most basic first request it will only give me a 500 Error on `localhost:3000` where my Nuxt app is running.

I try this in `app.vue`:

```
<template> 
  <div> 
    <p>Test</p> 
  </div> 
</template> 

<script setup> 

const { find } = useStrapi4() 
const response = await find('articles') 
console.log(response) 

</script>
```

And this is what is shown in the browser:

[image: screen shot]

My nuxt.config.ts looks like this

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({ 
  devtools: { enabled: true }, 
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/strapi'], 
  strapi: { url: process.env.STRAPI_URL || 'http:/localhost:1337', 
    prefix: '/api', 
    version: 'v4', 
    cookie: {}, 
    cookieName: 'strapi_jwt' 
  } 
})
```

Seems like something obvious I am just not seeing because it's just the standard setup I think.